# Объясните как работает этот блок кода. getchar, работа с массивом в цикле

Tags: c, массивы, циклы, char

Я практиковался в создании программы, симулирующую регистрацию. Я использовал некоторый блок кода из видео(пытался сделать пропуск оставшихся символов из входного буфера в массиве), чтобы после неудачной попытки ввода логина, алгоритм кода повторялся(но ведь он и должен повторяться, так как код находится в цикле и переменная `unregisted` - истинная. Но я так и не пойму алгоритм действия этого блока. Он же по идеи должен быть бесконечен? Почему обращение хоть к какому элементу в массиве `nickname[]` выдает один и тот же результат. Можно ли написать этот блок по-другому. Строка этого блока **48-50**.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define SIZE 19 //Ограничение в размере никнейма/пароля (подразумевается 20 
символов)

int main(void) {
char nickname[SIZE]; //Массив из символов, имеющий в себе никнейм/пароль
int i;
int num; //Порядковый номер символа в никнейме/пароле / реальный размер+1 никнейма/пароля
bool unregisted = true; //Проверяет, успешна ли прошла регистрация
bool check; //Проверяет, успех ввода логина/пароля
bool logined = false; //Проверяет, вошел ли аккаунт ранее или нет(позднее доразработать) (unused)

printf("Write your nickname, using english alphabet and figures: A-Z; a-z; 0-9.\n");
printf("(to confirm your nickname, type 'Enter):\n");

while(unregisted) {
    num = 0;
    check = true;

    while((nickname[num] = getchar()) != '\n') {

        if( ((nickname[num] >= '0') && (nickname[num] <= '9')) || 
            ((nickname[num] >= 'A') && (nickname[num] <= 'Z')) ||
            ((nickname[num] >= 'a') && (nickname[num] <= 'z')) && (check) && (num < SIZE)) { 
            num++;
        } //Идет проверка формальности ввода никнейма (цифры, заглавные буквы, цифры)
        else {
            check = false; 
            break;
        } 
    } //Ввод никнейма 

    printf("%d\n", num);

    if(check) {
        printf("You have comleted the registration of nickname!\n");

        printf("Your nickname ");

        for(i=0; i <= num-1; i++) 
            printf("%c", nickname[i]);

        printf(" is completly registed!\n");
        unregisted = false;
    } //Вывод успешного результата проверки формальности никнейма
    else {
            printf("Registration was unsuccesful, please, try again.\n");
            while((nickname[num] = getchar()) != '\n')
                continue; //очистка входного буффера от ранее используемых символов
    } //Повтор регистрации при неуспешном результате прошлой попытки зарегистрироваться
}

printf("You have comleted registration!\n");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте использовать отладчик, который специально предназначен для того, чтобы посмотреть как программа реально работает. Да и вообще пригодится

Comment: Что за странная идея - посимвольный ввод? Эта задача очень далека от реальности. Примите строку целиком, и потом проверяйте (только не забудьте НЕ использовать `gets()`)

Comment: И в дополнение к совету @ВладимирМартьянов: не городите сложных условий. Если в "ифе" столько проверок - стоит задуматься. И: 1) первая часть заменяется на `isalnum()` (подробности опущу). Во-вторых: http://xxo.su/resizer/i/3/0/e5ee031d.png (подумайте)

Comment: Если не считать ошибки в допустимом количестве вводимых символов, отсутствии реакции на EOF и явно избыточной проверки `check` в `if`-е в цикле ввода символов `nickname[]`, то код выглядит вполне работоспособным. Цикл ввода безусловно конечен (в нем переменной `unregistered` присваивается `false` (при определенных условиях)).  Уточните, что же именно вы хотели спросить?